# I can't find partititions while installing Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, partitioning, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubiquity doesn’t see any partitions on the Disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224979/ubiquity-doesnt-see-any-partitions-on-the-disk)

I'm running LiveCD Xubuntu on Windows 7. Once the installation begin, it shows:

> this computer currently has no detected operating system

When I click on `Something else` it shows me just one partition `/dev/sda/` which own the whole space 320GB. When I try to modify it, this will erase all the data in the HDD and I really need it.

When I enter in the terminal `sudo fdisk -l` it shows the following message:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320071851520 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625140335 sectors Units =
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d87ad

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sda1   *          63    97643069    48821503+   7 
 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda2        97656830   625141759   263742465    5
 Extended /dev/sda5        97656832   195309567    48826368    b  W95
 FAT32 /dev/sda6       195311616   292964351    48826368    b  W95
 FAT32 /dev/sda7       292966400   390619135    48826368    b  W95
 FAT32 /dev/sda8       390621184   488273919    48826368    b  W95
 FAT32 /dev/sda9       488275968   585928703    48826368    b  W95
 FAT32 /dev/sda10      585938808   625121279    19591236    7 
 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda11      585930752   585938744        3996+  83
 Linux

 Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: A couple of questions first. Are you planning to replace Windows 7 with Xubuntu? If no, does Windows 7 boot and work normally now?

Comment: No i don't want to remplace windows 7 with xubuntu , i want a dual-boot . and yes the windows 7 is working normally without problems

Comment: No problem then, good answers are already posted in [these](http://askubuntu.com/q/224979/12864) [three](http://askubuntu.com/q/43585/12864) [duplicates](http://askubuntu.com/q/69037/12864). Have a look and if that doesn't give you a working solution, please update your question with what you tried and the results. Good luck.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but is the WUBI useful ? i guess this is a short and a good idea